# How to manage the paired devices of a Player Input Component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-input

Hi I am trying to set up a multiplayer system with **Unity's** new **Input System**.

To do this I use a **player input manager object** to spawn and control players and a **player prefab object** as a player to spawn.

The **manager object** contains as expected a **player input manager** component, but also: a **player input** component (*To detect inputs when there are no players spawned; these are normally used by player objects*) and a **script** to manage joining and leaving players and receive inputs.

The **player prefab** object contains a **physical object** to control, a **player input** component and 2 **script's**: 1 to handel incoming inputs and 1 to control the physical object.

Joining players works. I just use:

`PlayerInputManager.JoinPlayer(Int32, Int32, String, InputDevice)`
(*This is documented* [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.PlayerInputManager.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_PlayerInputManager_JoinPlayer_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_String_UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputDevice_))

But I somtimes also want to remove or change which devices are set to a player or the manager, but I can't find what I need to do so.

I tried to find a function that does that for the **PlayerInput** class but I couldn't find anything.

I also tried to manipulate the **UserInput** struct (*which basically is a player's ID*) inside my object's **Player Input** component, but unlike the **Player Input Manager** I couldn't acces any documented properties. 
(*For this I looked* [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.PlayerInput.html#properties))

So there for my question: How do I acces **PlayerInputs** user ID and tweak it's paired devices?

Also if I made a mistake or you don't understand something let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

To change a **Player Input** component's properties I indeed need their **UserInput** struct.

But the trick was that I also needed the right **PlayerInput** class. (*Which are inside **Player input** components*)

To get one I needed to type:

`var myPlayerInput = PlayerInput.all[i];` (*i = the index*)

Than to get it's **UserInput** I type:

`var myUser = myPlayerInput.user;`

Now I can change any property of the referred **PlayerInput** class.

For example I can use this to remove controllers of a Player:

`myUser.UnpairDevice(InputDevice);`

(***InputDevice*** Should be a reference to a device)

Well that's this problem solved.

Hope it can help someone else too.

Edit: To get the **UserInput** in one go you can off course type:

`var myUser = PlayerInput.all[i].user;`

Comment: I'm very late, but is there a way to pair devices? The 'pairedDevices' is read only.